# What are valid methods of archiving EFK-stack data from a Kubernetes cluster automatically?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, elastic-stack, fluentd

My indices take up a lot of memory in my Kubernetes cluster after a few days. What would be the preferred method to export and archive these automatically?

Apologies if this is a rather simple and general question, but I can only find information on the internet of how to deploy the EFK-stack in a kubernetes cluster.